# Why even after putting await keyword my app will show 0?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, async-await, future, futuretask

I have called trigger function inside initState function.In trigger function i will be taking data from an API and i parsed the data using storeddata.fromjson function. Then afterwards i will store those values in variables. As far as i know initState function will be called as soon as object of this statefull widget is created. But still in app, it will show exchangeval_bitcoin as 0 for some seconds and then it will get updated(I have initialized exchangeval_bitcoin as 0). does that mean build function will be called even before completion of initState function even after putting await keyword ? And how can i implement loading screen until that value is updated ?

```
void triggerfun() async {
var decodedmap;
Jsonparse p = Jsonparse(url: uri);
decodedmap = await p.cryptocovert();
Storeddata s = Storeddata.fromjson(decodedmap);
setState(() {
  exchangeval_bitcoin = s.getdataforbitcoin();
  exchangeval_etherium = s.getdataforetherium();
  exchangeval_litecoin = s.getdataforlitecoin();
});
permanent = s;
}

//calling initstate
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
triggerfun();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

triggerfun() is an asynchronous function. So in your initState(), it's going to call triggerfun(), but still continue with the rest of your program. When trigger function is finished, it will set state and rebuild the widget.

The await keyword will stop the program until that line is finished, but triggerfun() as a whole is still asynchronous.

Comment: Oh ok I understood now. Any idea on how i can show loading screen until it sets those variable ? ( How should I set the duration as exact duration is unknown)

Comment: So I'm assuming the build section of your app displays the coin prices. I'd probably do something like set exchangeval_bitcoin in the state to null. And in the build section, if exchangeval_bitcoin is null, show a loading widget. The idea here is that you won't know how long it takes, so just show a loading widget if the variables are null. Once the variable is updated, your setState in triggerfun() will rebuild your widget with the new values for those variables.

Comment: Got it .Great idea. Thank you.

Comment: Flutter is getting interesting day by day. But only thing is I will be uncomfortable while creating  UI. I feel like not having absolute control and awareness while creating.